# using loops to create a new array that gets its values from a different array, starting on the second element and multiplying by the previous element

Tags: python, arrays, loops

I am trying to make a function that creates an array from the functions original array, that starts on the second element and multiplies by the previous element.
Example

```
input: [2,3,4,5]
output: [6,12,20]
```

I am trying to use a loop to get this done and here is my code so far

```
def funct(array1):
     newarray = []
     for x in array1[1:]:
          newarray.append(x*array1)
     return newarray
```

I am at a loss as I am just learning python, and i've tried various other options but with no success. Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
A = [2, 3, 4, 5]
output = [a*b for a, b in zip(A[1:], A[:-1])]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a list comprehension like so:

```
inp = [2,3,4,5]
out = [j * inp[i-1] for i,j in enumerate(inp) if i != 0]
```

Output:

```
[6,12,20]
```